# Port redirect with firewalld

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, firewalld

I'm trying to redirect  a traffic that goes to a certain port - to another port. I've read how to do it with iptables, but my system is using firewalld.
Here what I have for iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10080
```

And here is  what I think is the equivalent for firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd  --add-forward-port=80:proto=tcp:toport=10080
```

Is this this the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=10080
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```